# How can I re-utilise existing validation methods in my custom validation method in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-validation

Let's say we have the following custom validator:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('email_and_mx_record', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            //...
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

As implied by the validation name, I want to create MX record validation of an email address. First thing is first though, checking the email address format is valid. Now I know that this is simple enough if I simply copy the existing validation logic from the `Validator` class itself that uses a well known function:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Validation;

class Validator implements ValidatorContract
{
    /**
     * Validate that an attribute is a valid e-mail address.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed   $value
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function validateEmail($attribute, $value)
    {
        return filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false;
    }
}
```

But in an ideal world, I would want to stick to the DRY principle.

I am wondering if there is a way to call this method within my custom validator or not? E.g. (doesn't work): `return $validator->validateEmail($attribute, $value) ? (do my validation) : false;`.

The only solution to this question would be a way not to repeat myself, and piggy-back on the Laravel email validator. For now, I will just copy the existing logic.

If it is possible to do this, it would pave the way for me to enhance other validation methods, so it isn't just an issue of being pedantic.

Comment: You can always put them in a static class

Comment: If you have a solution please can you elaborate on it

Comment: By putting this validation rules inside a static class (static functions), you can call the validation functions from everywhere without the need for singletons or object passing.

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks

Comment: Throwing it in the wild, but what about using traits?

Comment: I would honestly much rather solutions, lol. But thanks, I'll take this as an idea as well

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling Laravel email validation function inside your custom validation, I'm wondering why can't you use the `email` rule as a rule only. There is no need of overriding.

For example :

`$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'bail|email|email_and_mx_record',
    ...
]);`

`bail` documentation :

> Sometimes you may wish to stop running validation rules on an
>   attribute after the first validation failure. To do so, assign the
>   bail rule to the attribute:

Comment: This is indeed a valid solution, but doesn't bail also return on the first error that occurs, attribute-wide? Or am I mistaken? I.e. it's a solution that has some use-case caveats if not mistaken. It is also implied that `email` format validation as per the standard email validation is done in the way I've worded my rule, so it's nicer not to remember to `bail|email|email_and_mx_record`, even if this one case is rather trivial. Thanks for your input so far though

Comment: I've re-read the docs on `bail` and perhaps this really is a good enough solution to the problem. The only issue that remains is either renaming the rule so it isn't implied that the email format is also checked e.g. just `email_mx_record`, or finding another way.

Comment: I'll mark this is correct later this evening after mulling it over, as it solves the problem but I'm not sure if it's the way I wanted it to be solved if you know what I mean!